# Continuous press of button in Playback Overlay fragment in leanback library

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I am using playback overlay fragment in my Android TV app for video controls.The problem is I want to know whether the buttons are continuously pressed or not.But in callback I only come to know when its pressed .

```
this.mPlayBackControlsRowPresenter.setOnActionClickedListener(new OnActionClickedListener() {
        public void onActionClicked(Action action) {
            PlaybackControlFragment playbackControlFragment = (PlaybackControlFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.playback_controls_fragment);
            if (action.getId() == playbackControlFragment.getPlayPause().getId()) {
                /* PlayPause action */
            } else if (action.getId() == playbackControlFragment.getPlayNext().getId()) {
                /* SkipNext action */
               // mMediaController.getTransportControls().skipToNext();
            } else if (action.getId() == playbackControlFragment.getPlayPrevious().getId()) {
                /* SkipPrevious action */
               // mMediaController.getTransportControls().skipToPrevious();
            } else if (action.getId() == playbackControlFragment.getForward().getId()) {
                /* FastForward action  */
              //  mMediaController.getTransportControls().fastForward();
            } else if (action.getId() == playbackControlFragment.getRewind().getId()) {
                /* Rewind action */
              //  mMediaController.getTransportControls().rewind();
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: Even if there is a way to know where the current focus is in playback controls it will be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

If user continuously presses the button then multiple events will be triggered, you can write a logic around that for successive events and modify behavior according to the state